# Automatically run R code when RStudio project is opened

Tags: r, rstudio

I wrote an R function that updates the version number of a package in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13029847/567015). I work a lot with GitHub and RStudio, and it would safe me quite some time (plus be much more precise) if this function was automatically run every time I opened a certain project (or better yet, make a git commit/push, but I assume that is harder to do). But I don't know how to do this or if this is even possible.

I could use `.Rprofile` to run R codes every time I start `R`, so I could just update versions whenever I start R (or build in that it only updates the version if the date is not today or something) but that seems overdoing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a separate `.Rprofile` for each project. You have to put it in the main directory of the project (http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/projects).

Comment: Perfect! I put a small piece of code with `utils:::menu` in there and now every time I open the project I am asked if i want to update the package version. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Well I would use `.Rprofile` for that.  There is something to be said for being independent of the tool chain around you: knitr works from RStudio as well as without it, dito for Rcpp/RInside etc pp.

You can hook into commit hooks for svn, both explicitly via hooks in the back end, or simply at your by end adding wrapper scripts.  I presume you can do likewise with git but I simply know much less about it.  So to abstract this away, I would write myself a 'commitThis' or 'pushThis' or ... function that does the number increment, test run, code push and what have you.

Answer (score 0):

If your code needs RStudio to be already running (e.g. because it's relying on some `rstudioapi::` function), putting it directly in `.Rprofile` won't work (`.Rprofile` is executed before RStudio is available).

Instead, you could set a [hook for `"rstudio.sessionInit"`](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/r_sessions/session_startup_scripts.html):

```r
setHook(
  hookName = "rstudio.sessionInit",
  action = function(newSession) {
    if (newSession) {
      # your code goes here
    },
  action = "append"
)
```