# How to run code when opening Rstudio?

Tags: r, function, rstudio

I have a function stored on my local drive and I want that when Rstudio is opened, the function is executed.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13031380/8382207